# Multiple parameters for @selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, nsinvocation

I am creating a game in objective C, and I am stopped by a matter : I have a warning for passing multiple variables on @selector.
What I want to do, is call a method in my UIViewController but after a delay. So I try to make a first method, that call the other after delay like this :

```
-(void)AnimationCoinInitWith_x:(int)x y:(int)y w:(int)w h:(int)h afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)t
{
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(AnimationCoinCopyInitWith_x:y:w:h:)]];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(AnimationCoinCopyInitWith_x:y:w:h:)];
    [invocation setArgument:x atIndex:1];
    [invocation setArgument:y atIndex:2];
    [invocation setArgument:w atIndex:3];
    [invocation setArgument:h atIndex:4];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:t invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
}

-(void)AnimationCoinCopyInitWith_x:(int)x y:(int)y w:(int)w h:(int)h
{
    UIImageView* imageViewCoin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
    [imageViewCoin setAnimationImages:images];
    [imageViewCoin setAnimationRepeatCount:1000];
    [imageViewCoin setAnimationDuration:(1/24)];
    [imageViewCoin startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:imageViewCoin];
    [imageViewCoin release];
}
```

But it's not working, I don't know why.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please post the exact (compiler?) warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, your problem is that `NSInvocation` doesn't automagically set the offsets of arguments you need, and as all objective-c methods have two invisible arguments (`self` and `_cmd`), you must offset your argument indices by 2, not 1.

Another issue here is that you are failing to pass the arguments by reference, so you must use the address operator (`&`):

```
[invocation setArgument:&x atIndex:2];
[invocation setArgument:&y atIndex:3];
[invocation setArgument:&w atIndex:4];
[invocation setArgument:&h atIndex:5];
```

Once you do that, your code above should work fine.

Comment: I have a warning with this code : Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'void *';

Comment: @user2057209 correct, I just realized that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like working, i've got an error for bad access but your code is working ! Thanks !! =)

Comment: I could'nt before because you were too fast ahah ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, we adopted a policy of avoiding NSInvocation except when absolutely necessary because the code tends to be hard to read, fragile, and a headache when refactoring (and a source of bugs).

Also, by avoiding NSInvocation and using straightforward call sites, the compiler is fully able to validate the code.

You can use the "dispatch_after" pattern:

```
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     [self animationCoinInitWith_x: ...];
    });
```

Or, if you want to stick with -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: (which I find more readable):

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)invokeBlock:(dispatch_block_t)aBlock
{
    aBlock();
}

- (void)doIt:(int)x toIt:(int)y
{
    NSLog(@"%s %d %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, x, y);
}
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Foo* foo = [Foo new];
        dispatch_block_t block = ^{
            [foo doIt:10 toIt:10];
        };
        [foo performSelector:@selector(invokeBlock:) withObject:[block copy] afterDelay:5];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above assumes ARC (hence, the lack of releases).